# Variables in Ruby class method names

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

`object.send(invoked_method_name)` is very useful. But i need to do it on class like `Model.send(method_name_by_variable)` and this I can't do. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you? If the method is on the class scope, and you do that.. it'll call it. It's no different from doing so on an instance of the class. A Class is an instance of Class which also inherits from Object

Comment: Are you talking about getting a value of @@some_variable via send?

Comment: What is the error message? Are you passing a variable that holds the method name as String or Symbol, right?

Comment: perhaps you need `Model.new.send(method_name_by_variable)`?

Comment: @slivu, why would he need to instantiate an unnecessary temporary object when he already has the `Class` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.send(method_name_by_variable)` should be possible,if

- `method_name_by_variable` is in the scope of `Model`

How you can test it (I use `String` in my examples, with `Model` is should be the same.

**Scope**

test if your method is a public method:

```
method_name_by_variable = :new
p String.public_methods.include?(method_name_by_variable) #-> true
p 'aa'.public_methods.include?(method_name_by_variable)  #-> false
```

Comment: @FrederickCheung is right. It's fine to pass the method name to `send` as a String.

Comment: You are right, it works also with strings. I was wrong with my guess. It's only needed for the test with `Object#public_methods.include?`I corrected my answer.